# Native Messaging host not able to send 1 MB data

Tags: c++, google-chrome, visual-c++, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am using the native-host in C++, when i send base64 from the native app to chrome extension(Native messaging) with size base64 < 1M, the program is still running. but when i send base64 from the native app to chrome extension (Native messaging) with size base64 >1M, the program is error "Error when communicating with the native messaging host" 
my code below

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::unitbuf );
    unsigned int c, t=0;
    inp="";
    t=0;
    // Sum the first 4 chars from stdin (the length of the message passed).
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        //t += getchar();
        t += std::pow(256.0f, i) * getchar();
    }
    // Loop getchar to pull in the message until we reach the total
    //  length provided.
    for (int i=0; i < t; i++) {
        c = getchar();
        inp += c;
    }

    unsigned int len =  inp.length();
    // We need to send the 4 btyes of length information
    std::cout << char(((len>>0) & 0xFF))
              << char(((len>>8) & 0xFF))
              << char(((len>>16) & 0xFF))
              << char(((len>>24) & 0xFF));
    // Now we can output our message
    std::cout << inp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, where is the question...? What do you want to know?

Comment: Yeah, this is by design, they simply don't accept messages greater than 1M.  You need to break it down into a series of smaller messages and re-assemble the data in the extension.

Comment: @donaddon Do you have a source for your claim?

Answer (score 4):

Native messaging hosts cannot send a message with more than 1024*1024 bytes. From

https://cs.chromium.org/file%3Anative_message_process_host.cc%20kMaximumMessageSize:

```cpp
// Maximum message size in bytes for messages received from Native Messaging
// hosts. Message size is limited mainly to prevent Chrome from crashing when
// native application misbehaves (e.g. starts writing garbage to the pipe).
const size_t kMaximumMessageSize = 1024 * 1024;
```

To work around this problem, you have to split the message sent from the native messaging host to your extension/app in chunks of less than 1MB.
In your native messaging host, you could create a loop that repeatedly outputs the 32-bit message length (max 1MB) followed by a chunk of the message.
In your app/extension, use [`chrome.runtime.connectNative`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connectNative) instead of [`chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendNativeMessage) to open a port that lasts longer than one message (if you use `sendNativeMessage`, the port will be closed after receiving one reply, which causes the native messaging host to terminate).

Comment: Thank you very much for an appropriate source link. That said, this state of affairs is pretty regrettable.

Comment: @Xan What is regrettable? The 1MB limitation, the work-around, or the native messaging documentation?

Comment: The limitation. An already awkward messaging protocol being even more awkward. And, of course, the fact that it's not documented.

Comment: @Xan An unlimited message size (native app -> Chrome browser) is dangerous, so there must be some maximum message size. This limit will be documented, see the preview at https://chrome-apps-doc.appspot.com/_patch/768373004/extensions/messaging#native-messaging. I submitted a patch last week, but the reviewer is apparently on leave. Here is the patch, let me know if you have any suggestions for improvements: https://codereview.chromium.org/768373004/.